# Cardinal of the family of all finite subsets of rational numbers contained in [0,1]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the set $\mathbb{H}=\{ H: H \subseteq [0,1] \cap\mathbb{Q}, |H|< \infty \}$ countable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

We know that $\mathbf{card}(\mathbb Q) = \aleph_0$. As $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q$ and $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ is not finite, we can conclude that $\mathbf{card}([0,1] \cap \mathbb Q) = \aleph_0$. Said differently $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ is countable.

For any $n\in \mathbb N^*$ the number of subsets of size $n$ of a countable set is countable, what is often written ${\aleph_0}^n = \aleph_0$.

When you considere the set of all finite subsets, you are building a countable union of countable sets. Which is countable because it is no more than $\mathbf{card}(\mathbb N \times \mathbb N) = {\aleph_0}^2 = \aleph_0$